# Merge numerous .txt files into one. Win/Cygwin

Tags: text, command-line, concatenation

I have 500 .txt files and I need to merge them into 1 .txt file. I could do this manually by hand but it would take a long time. I'm wondering if there's an easier way via command line? I would need a new line character between each .txt file's contents in the end text file. I'm running Windows 7 but also have Cygwin installed.

Comment: `cd /path/to/data ; cat *.txt > output.dat` (Don't use `.txt` exten for your output file), then `mv output.dat output.txt` (Or if you may not need this). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You may place all the txt files into a folder.
2. Open Window CMD
3. Move to that folder and Run this command

`for %f in (*.txt) do type "%f" >> output.txt`

All the files will be merged into output.txt